# Query MySQL database with timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql, database, timestamp

I have a timestamp field [SubmissionDate], which defaults to current_timestamp, and i was wondering how do i query my database in such a fashion that for example i get only shown all entries submitted on a certain year and month?
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM DNA_entrys
WHERE `SubmissionDate`.month = February
AND `SubmissionDate`.year = 2004
```

Should be an elementary operation but i couldn't find a quick answer on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM DNA_entrys
WHERE month(`SubmissionDate`) = 2
AND year(`SubmissionDate`) = 2004
```

tho i suggest:

```
SELECT * FROM DNA_entrys
WHERE `SubmissionDate` between '2004-02-01' and ('2004-03-01' - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

latter allows use of indexes, which makes query faster if you have ithat field indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT * FROM DNA_entrys
WHERE MONTH(SubmissionDate) = 2
AND YEAR(SubmissionDate) = 2004
```